# Bound TextBox Text Does not Update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having a problem with the textbox text updating in my view.  I have seen some other threads but cannot find one that is close to my setup.

I have a model with a class of

```
    interface IPerson : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       string FirstName { get; set;}    
    }

    public class Person
    {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
      private string _firstName;
      public string FirstName
      { 
           get {return _firstName;}
           set 
           {
             _firstName = value;
             PropertyChanged(this , new PropertChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
           }
       }
     }
```

This is what my viewModel Looks Like

```
    interface IViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      string FirstName { get; set;}
      IPerson Person { get; set; }
    }
    public class viewModel : IViewModel
    {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
      private IPerson _person;
      public Person Person
      { 
        get {return _person;}
        set 
            {
               _person = value;
                PropertyChanged(this , new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Person"));
            }
       }          
       public string FirstName
       {
          get {return Person.FirstName;}
          Set 
          {
              Person.FirstName = value;
              PropertyChanged(this , new PropertChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
           }

        }
    }
```

Xaml Binding Setup

```
// If i use this binding my model will get updated but my textbox text will never show what the value is in the model
Text="{Binding Path=FirstName ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay,diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"

// This binding works fine both ways
Text="{Binding Path=Person.FirstName ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay,diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
```

So if i bind to the Person.First Name everything works great.  If I bind to FirstName then it will update my model fine but will not get the data for The TextBox Text.  This becomes apparent when i select an item in my list.

Does anyone have an idea why this would happen.  I want to be able to bind to the ViewModel Firstname and just have it pass that to my person object.

Comment: What is your DataContext? According to code i think its viewModel. So if property is changed in Person Then viewModel  clas will not get notified if you use Just FirstName. So try firing PropertyChanged in viewModel.

Comment: This is how I do my DataContext                                         public EmployeeAdministrationView(IEmployeeAdministrationViewModel vm) : this()
        {
            DataContext = vm;
        }

Comment: I think by accident i just deleted someone's comment.  I do apologize.  They had asked me my dataContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model changes the FirsName value it triggers an PropertyChanged event but that is not extended (relayed) by the ViewModel.

To make the first binding work your ViewModel should subscribe to Person.PropertyChanged and then raise its own event when the nested FirstName changes.

But of course the `Path=Person.FirstName` binding is preferable anyway.

Comment: OK I will just leave the binding with Path=Person.FirstName.  Especially if it is preferable anyways.  Thanks for you help

Comment: @Bret - to be clear, it is the copy of FirstName that is undesirable. And would take even more work to do right.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by copy.  I was just trying to have my view model hold my property which would just pass off to the person.FirstName  using the gets and sets.  The set works perfect its just the textbox when bound with just FirstName of the view model will not show the text.  If i type text in it does update my model which was confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

With this binding "Binding Path=Person.FirstName" the View is listening to your viewModel for the PropertyChanged event. The View is not listening to your model (i.e. Person).

If you are setting the DataContext of your View to the viewModel, then in order for the View to know about changes to your model (i.e. person) you are going to have to have your viewModel listen for the PropertyChanged event of your model. Then, raise the PropertyChanged event from within your viewModel.